# Every IRQ and ISR causes a GPF

Tags: assembly, kernel, osdev, irq, isr

I am developing an operating system. My GDT has three entries. I've created the IDT and implemented ISR and IQR. I also remapped the PIC. The problem is that after every interrupt handler follows a General Protection Fault.
This is the assembly code which calls the interrupts:

```
.extern fault_handler
isr_common_stub: 
    pusha
    push %ds
    push %es
    push %fs
    push %gs
    movw $0x10,%ax # Load the Kernel Data Segment descriptor!
    movw %ax,%ds
    movw %ax,%es
    movw %ax,%fs
    movw %ax,%gs
    movl %esp,%eax # Push us the stack
    pushl %eax
    movl $fault_handler, %eax
    call *%eax     # A special call, preserves the 'eip' register
    popl %eax
    popl %gs # I discovered that the error occures on this line
    popl %fs
    popl %es
    popl %ds
    popa
    addl $8,%esp   # Cleans up the pushed error code and pushed ISR number
    iret           # pops 5 things at once: CS, EIP, EFLAGS, SS, and ESP!

.extern irq_handler
irq_common_stub: 
    pusha
    push %ds
    push %es
    push %fs
    push %gs
    movw $0x10,%ax
    movw %ax,%ds
    movw %ax,%es
    movw %ax,%fs
    movw %ax,%gs
    movl %esp,%eax
    pushl %eax
    movl $irq_handler, %eax
    call *%eax
    popl %eax
    popl %gs # I discovered that the error occures on this line
    popl %fs
    popl %es
    popl %ds
    popa
    addl $8,%esp
    iret
```

I found out something strange. When I run the operating system with QEMU as an `.iso` disk image, it does not work. But when I called it as a kernel by specifying the `-kernel` option, it worked as expected. I decided to change the code below:

```
    popl %gs # I discovered that the error occures on this line
    popl %fs
    popl %es
    popl %ds
```

I changed the code above to this:

```
    pop %gs
    pop %fs
    pop %es
    pop %ds
```

I am still getting the GPF. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: One odd thing is that you are doing `push` but then `popl`... generally should use the same `push`/`pop` or `pushl`/`popl`

Comment: Is your `gs` initialized properly? If it has some leftover value from real mode, then popping that back will cause a GPF. PS: learn to use a debugger  PS #2: `special call, preserves the 'eip' register` LOL?

Answer (score 3):

If my old memory serves me correctly, the segment registers are 16 bits, and you're trying to do a `popl` which pops a 32-bit value... thus that's a problem.

Since you're doing a `push %gs` above, you should also do a `pop %gs`.  Same with the other registers, make sure you `pop` them the same way you `push` them.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>    addl $8,%esp   # Cleans up the pushed error code and pushed ISR number
> ```

Your *isr_common_stub* routine thinks that an error code will always be there. Some faults don't push an error code! Only faults related to interrupt numbers 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 17 use an error code.

From http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev15.html we learn:

> If the handler is going to be executed at a lower privilege level (bits 42-45 of descriptor), a stack switch occurs.
>   The segment selector and stack pointer for the stack to be used by the handler are abtained from the TSS for the currently executing task. The processor pushes the stack segment selector and stack pointer of the interrupt handler on this new stack.The processor saves the current state of EFLAGS,CS, and EIP on the new stack.
>   **If an exception causes an error code to be saved**, the error code is pushed on the new stack after EIP.

and also

> If the handler is going to be executed at the same privilege level (current privilege level (cpl) is the same as (bits 42-45 of descriptor)
>   The processor saves the current state of EFLAGS, CS, EIP on the current stack.
>   **If an exception causes an error code to be saved**, the error code is pushed on the current stack after EIP

It is very important to know how the stack is pushed when our interrupt handler is called, and what exceptions also push error codes.